# Forward diode characteristics not starting from zero Ampere

Tags: mosfet, diodes, h-bridge, body-diode

Why the current is not starting from zero, whats the diode characteristic when current is near zero?

Reading the datasheet for N-channel 60V MOSFET, I encountered this source-drain characteristic of the diode, but I don’t understand how to find diode on-state zero-current voltage here, as current doesn’t start from zero on characteristic.

[Here](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/021/DOC001021082.pdf) you can find the datasheet for MOSFET.

[image: Source-drain diode forward characteristics]

EDIT:

I want to understand if the diode will conduct lower currents, comparing with other MOSFET characteristics, where you can clearly see how it behaves when the current is near zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below 0.8V, the body diode gets dominated by the exponential (log I vs V) below  0.6V and above 0.8V has a bulk incremental resistance, Rs ( or Ri) here shown as **4.4 mΩ**, which is much less than the **RdsOn < 16 mΩ.**

## pro bono info

Yet, the start of the curve at 0.82V, the body diode resistance is **0.05 Ω.**

The body diode threshold is near 0.6V @ 1mA @ 25'C which is equivalent to **600 Ω**
Also the FET Vgs(th) of 4V max at 250 uA is equivalent to **16 Ω.**

[image]

Comment: I wonder who voted -1 .... rookie I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Since diodes aren't magically able to generate energy out of thin air, without potential difference, i.e. at a zero voltage across that diode, no current flows.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Maybe i wasnt quite clear. I made an edit to the answer. I want to understand how diode behaves when current is near zero

Comment: @Vaso It will behave in a similar way to any diode at near zero currents. To know more precisely you will have to measure it yourself. Also "near zero" looks simple but isn't. Is 1 nA "near zero" or 1 uA ? Since this is a power MOSFET the diode will be large and might leak. It might leak more than 1nA that changes the behavior "near zero".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, but what will be for example at 1A current, and why they didnt show it on characteristics?

Comment: @Vaso 1 A isn't "near zero", why don't you just extrapolate the curve from the first plot in your question, then at 1 A at +25C my guess is a voltage between 0.7 and 0.8 V. Similar to many "normal" silicon power diodes. ST didn't show it because they didn't think it was needed to measure that (which costs money). Also the diode is a "parasitic" component, it is the MOSFET that matters, not the diode.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Alright thanks, i thought that there can be some other reason for why they didn’t presented characteristics at current lower than 15 A here.